# How override fields of the registration form in Flask-Security?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

How do I override the default registration form in Flask-Security is to remove all label attributes.
In the documentation there is a section of the customizing view, but in the example is to add the fields to the form, and I need to change the default.

Answer (score 2):

I did this by editing the _macros.html file in the flask-security library, by default it looks like this:

```
{% macro render_field_with_errors(field) %}
  <p>
    {{ field.label }} {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </p>
{% endmacro %}
```

source: https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/c7d0ea9cceb5d2fab7b98a21579da86aa2a3c20b/flask_security/templates/security/_macros.html

To remove labels, remove the label expansion:

```
{% macro render_field_with_errors(field) %}
  <p>
    {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </p>
{% endmacro %}
```

The file for me (using venv) was in this path, you might want to find it with find or otherwise:
./venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_security/templates/security/_macros.html